# Get Developer Token dynamically of a Box Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, box-api, box

```
require 'boxr'

client = Boxr::Client.new('my_developer_token')

folder = client.folder_from_path("path/to/a/folder")
file = client.upload_file('filename.ext', folder)
updated_file = client.create_shared_link_for_file(file, access: :open)
puts "Shared Link: #{updated_file.shared_link.url}"
```

I have created a Ruby script which uploads a file to my Box and generate its shared link. The problem is a developer token expires in 30 or 60 minutes. So, I wanna create it dynamically using any gem/api and use it in `client = Boxr::Client.new('my_developer_token')`

How do I do it?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue with this, did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jwt, the expiration of the token will be taken care of.

https://github.com/cburnette/boxr/blob/master/examples/jwt_auth.rb

Comment: How would you go about creating a `client` then? For example, `client = Boxr::Client.new('{BOX_DEVELOPER_TOKEN}')` would be how with JWT?

Comment: `client.folder_from_id(folder_id)` I am now unable to get the folder. I wonder if is because I'm not using `DEVELOPER_TOKEN`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct and following the above answer by @kendomen you can use JWT to get around this.

```
token = Boxr::get_enterprise_token(private_key: ENV.fetch('JWT_PRIVATE_KEY'), private_key_password: ENV.fetch('JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD'), public_key_id: ENV.fetch('JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_ID'), enterprise_id: ENV.fetch('BOX_ENTERPRISE_ID'), client_id: ENV.fetch('BOX_CLIENT_ID'), client_secret: ENV.fetch('BOX_CLIENT_SECRET'))
```

Then you will pass this token when you generate your client:

```
client = Boxr::Client.new(token)
folder = client.folder_from_path("path/to/a/folder")
file = client.upload_file('filename.ext', folder)
updated_file = client.create_shared_link_for_file(file, access: :open)
puts "Shared Link: #{updated_file.shared_link.url}"
```